# If Statement in function does not evaluate

Tags: functions, conditional

I've written a function that should try to simulate a "triangle-wave-signal", given a few parameters. It looks like this:

```
tria[p_, s_, t_, ts_] := (
Module[{pps = s/(2 p), z = 0, cs = 0, cpos = 0, spp = 2/(s/(2 p)), 
ct = 0, ret = {}},
  For[i = 0, i < 2 p, i++, 
    For[j = 0, j < pps, j++,
      AppendTo[ret, {ct, cs}];
      ct = ct + ts;
      cpos += 1;
      spp *= If[TrueQ[cpos == s/(2 p)], cpos = 0; -1, 1, 1];
      cs += spp;
    ];
  ]; ret
 ]
)
```

Most of it is unimportant, but here is the line that doesn't work:

```
spp *= If[TrueQ[cpos == s/(2 p)], cpos = 0; -1, 1, 1];
```

I don't know if I'm right, but I have a feeling that the If-Statement simply doesn't do anything. I can also write it in a way that the multiplication happens inside the statement, but still, nothing changes. Weirdly, if I execute this If-Statement alone (Outside of the function), it works... What am I missing here? Why isn't it working like it should?

Comment: Remove the `TrueQ` part. The expression `cpos == s/(2 p)` will evaluate to `True` or `False` when numbers are plugged in already.

Comment: By the way, you can check to see if that expression is doing anything by wrapping the expression `cpos == s/(2 p)` ins `Sow` `Sow[cpos == s/(2 p)]` and when you run the function using `Reap`: `Reap@tria[1, 4, 2, 1]` will return a list: the first element is the output of the function and the second element is a list of the instances of the `Sow`ed expression. In this case, it clearly is doing something. `Reap`-`Sow` is nice for debugging, among many other things. By the way, what makes you think it's not doing anything?

Comment: @march Weird, last time I tried removing the TrueQ it didn't work... Now it does. Thanks a lot! Now I just have to fix it so it ranges from -1 to 1 instead of 0 to 2, but that should be easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 3;
b = 2;
c = 4;

Plot[a TriangleWave[b x + c], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: This is nice, but I need to be able to control the amount of dots I have while also controlling the horizontal axis... I hope what I just said makes sense, I somehow feel like it doesnt.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "amount of dots."  The amplitude, period and phase of the triangle wave are governed by a, b and c in my code.